# ssh dns spoofing warning - possible investigation?

Tags: man-in-the-middle, wireless, dns-spoofing

Recently the router my ISP provided started to work suspiciously. At times the wireless connection from my devices to the router breaks and the router stops responding while sometimes the connection to the ISP is lost altogether.

I would shrug it off as a kind of technical problem but I am also sporadically receiving the following messages when I ssh to some of my (different) servers

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@       WARNING: POSSIBLE DNS SPOOFING DETECTED!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
The RSA host key for ??? has changed,
and the key for the corresponding IP address ???
is unknown. This could either mean that
DNS SPOOFING is happening or the IP address for the host
and its host key have changed at the same time.
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
00:19:df:3d:18:82:a5:91:36:3c:60:0e:db:b1:a1:dc.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /home/???/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ECDSA key in /home/???/.ssh/known_hosts:1
  remove with: ssh-keygen -f "/home/???/.ssh/known_hosts" -R ???
RSA host key for ??? has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

After a while, the message disappears and I am able to log in smoothly. Similarly while I browse the web I've noticed that sometimes instead of the asked page some other random page appears. As you can see on the screenshot bellow.
[image]

What could potentially be going on? ISP's support is suggesting we just change the wireless router but I suspect there may be something else going on here.

I am not a security expert and I apologize if the question is not even suitable to this site but I would like to ask:

> What kind of investigation could be done in this situation? What could
>   be going on?

The host system is an Ubuntu machine that I believe not to be compromised. The same kind of behaviour is exhibited by other machines connected to this wireless network.

**Edit.** Here is also the (only?) relevant part of the diagnostics page of the router.

[image]

**Edit.** Content of /etc/resolv.conf and /etc/ppp/resolv.conf is

```
$ cat /etc/ppp/resolv.conf
nameserver 193.2.67.8
nameserver 193.2.67.9

$ cat /etc/resolv.conf

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search mydomain.it
```

Comment: Change the wifi password, change the admin password on the router, check the DNS settings on the router.

Comment: @schroeder I can only change the password for the access point. I've also included a screnshot from the diagnostic page indicating the router is not able to establish its link with the default gateway/DNS.

Comment: If you can't login to the management interface on your ISP- supplied router, you need to contact your ISP and check the DNS settings on that thing.

Comment: @shift_tab I can log in but the user interface does not offer any kind of useful info. The DNSs listed on the diagnostic page are 212.18.32.10,212.18.32.12 which seem to be from the ISP.

Comment: Duplicate? http://serverfault.com/questions/104316/ssh-warning-remote-host-identification-has-changed

Comment: @NeilSmithline No that's not the same issue. In the linked case the server in question actually changed the keys/IP. In this case this message is shown randomly and is also followed by weird DNS resolutions.

Comment: There's definitely some sort of DNS issue here going on then. Can you check the DNS settings on your machine, and can you check and verify the proxy settings in your browser? As for the SSH stuff, does your target machine get its IP from DHCP? It's possible that the IP has just changed and that will flag that message.

Comment: @shift_tab FF is configured to use system's proxy settings. I've also posted the content of /etc/resolv.conf and /etc/ppp/resolv.conf. The former seems to have some suspicious entry (mydomain.it?) in it. Is there any other file I should have a look at?

Comment: Change your DNS settings to a known good DNS server, such as Google's at 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4. If your issues continue, it could be a compromised router injecting data. If the issue subsides, it could have been a poisoned DNS server.

Comment: @pr- I've changed my DNS settings and it appears each time I connect online they change to the suspicious mydomain.it thing.

Comment: So you removed 'search mydomain.it' out of resolv.conf and it keeps coming back up? Could you please try and open up a terminal window and type in 'sudo chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf' -- this should "lock" resolv.conf so it's not edited by some program or daemon upon restart. I think DHCP or something else may be modifying your resolv.conf file. Please let me know if this works.

Comment: shift_tab They keep coming back, yes. And so do the spoofing warnings. As far as the chattr thing, it looks like it's a no-no chattr: Operation not supported while reading flags on /etc/resolv.conf I've also tried doing this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128220/how-do-i-set-my-dns-on-ubuntu-14-04 but the mydomain.it thing keeps coming back.

Comment: I looked through that thread, Jernej. I'm stumped at this point. I'll keep researching. Please let me know if you find the cause for that DNS entry populating.